# making behavior of p:messages like the p:growl (waiting somes seconds and hide)

Tags: validation, primefaces, components, message

I have one `p:messages`in the header of my `p:dialog`  and I want to hide it after some secondes (like behavior of `p:growl`)
here it is :

```
<p:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true"  showDetail="true" />
```

is it possible

thank you

Comment: Did you try some solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript, create javascript function and call in "oncomplete" function, for ex:

component:

```
 <p:commandButton oncomplete="testfm()"  />
```

javascript:

```
function testfm(){
                window.setTimeout(function testfm1(){
                    $(".ui-message-error").hide();
                },5000);
            }
```